# Solr error, unknown field

Tags: php, xml, solr

I just started using [Solr php client](https://code.google.com/archive/p/solr-php-client/). First I defined a schema for my data that I want to add to the index

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<schema name="qullet" version="1.2">
    <fields>
        <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" 
                   stored="true" required="true"/>
        <field name="title" type="string" indexed="true"
                   stored="true" required="true"/>
        <field name="description" type="text" indexed="true"
                   stored="true" required="true"/>
        <field name="test" type="text" indexed="true"
                   stored="true" required="true"/>
    </fields>
    <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
</schema>
```

Adding data to the index gives me the following error

```
"400" Status: ERRORunknown_field_test
```

If I remove the field test everything works fine.

Comment: have you restarted Solr / reloaded the Solr core?

Comment: thanks I restarted solr and I get " Unknown fieldtype 'string' specified on field id"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `<fieldType>`s. See the [sample schema.xml](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/trunk/solr/example/solr/conf/schema.xml?view=markup) for reference.

Comment: Do I have to extend this sample schema.xml with my fields? I worked with this tutorial and there where no types defined http://drupal.ayalon.ch/en/code-samples/solr-php-client-example

Comment: @ArtWorkAD notice the '...' between `<schema>` and `<fields>`, that's where the fieldTypes come in.

Comment: @ArtWorkAD the author probably assumed editing the sample schema.xml that comes with Solr.

Comment: do I have to remove all existing <field> elements and replace them with my own? when I do so it gives me an error again

Comment: thanks, I just remove most <field> elements and added my own now it works